# How to determine type of callback's input parameters in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have an function:

```
const myFunc = (callback: (...params: any) => void, params: [any]): void => {
   callback(...params);
};
//sample of using
myFunc((name: string) => { console.log(name) }, ["Mark"])
```

The myFunc takes callback and parameters. How to avoid "any" and provide that params in both case have same type?
p.s. (callback: (...params: T) => void, params: [T]) = doesn't work...

Comment: Do all parameters have the same type? Do you expect the same number of parameters?

Comment: yes - all parameters will have same type, number of parameters can by dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types):

```
const myFunc = <T extends unknown[]>(
  callback: (...params: T) => void,
  params: T
): void => {
   callback(...params);
};

myFunc((name: string) => {}, ["Mark"]); // OK
myFunc((name: string, age: number) => {}, ["Mark", 23]); // OK

myFunc((name: string) => {}, ["Mark", 23]); // Error
myFunc((name: string, city: string) => {}, ["Mark", 23]); // Error
```

If you know all parameters to be of the same type, you can use that type (e.g. `string`) instead of `unknown`.